# geom_histogram() to hist() in R

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
mapping <- aes(
  x = values
  , color = factor(par_a)
)

plot <- (ggplot(data=data, mapping=mapping)
         + geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, na.rm = TRUE)
         + facet_grid(par_b ~ par_c ~ par_d, scales = "free")
)
```

Since I am asked to use instead `hist()` because of the possibility to use `plot=FALSE`, now I want to adjust the code.

```
mapping <- aes(
      x = values
      , color = factor(par_a)
    )

plot2 <- hist(values, breaks = seq(min(values), max(values)+5, by = 5))
         + facet_grid(par_b ~ par_c ~ par_d, scales = "free")
```

However, I have no idea how to implement the 'color = factor(par_a)' or the whole line 'facet_grid(par_b ~ par_c ~ par_d, scales = "free")'. I guess these functions are not explicitly supported for 'hist()', but I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what the alternatives for them would be?

Comment: Hi, what is your `values` and  `data`? Please provide example data using `dput`.

Comment: "because of the possibility to use plot=FALSE" Then you could use `cut` and `table` instead. In any case, you will need a "group-by"-type function.

Answer (score 1):

the base plotting can use the function `par(mfrow=c(num_rows,num_cols))` in order to build subplots. The next plot, hist, etc. calls that you make will fill the desired subplots. and to color your bars within the plots you can make a variable as described [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/83-histogram-with-colored-tail.html) to pass to the color parameter of `hist`.